# How to run installed oh my fish plugins?

Tags: command-line, configuration, plugins, fish

I've successfully installed on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS fish shell and [oh my fish](https://github.com/oh-my-fish). One of the main appeals of this shell, for me, is the set of optional plugins.

I succesfully managed to install some plugins such as hash and [extract](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/plugin-extract/blob/master/functions/extract.fish) using

```
omf install extract
omf install hash
```

however, when I run

```
hash -q md5 "Hello world"
```

in the console I get no output at all (instead of the expected md5 hash of the string)

when I run

```
extract file.tar.gz
```

I get

```
The program 'extract' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install extract
```

which is not at all what I was expecting.

How can I make the plugins work? So far I've understood that I can put some fish shell scripts in the folder ~/.config/fish/functions and they will run. I can probably fix this by putting the code of the plugins in this folder but I'd like to know which is the official way of making the plugins work.

Comment: Did you run `hash` and `extract` in a new shell? It may be necessary to reload config file – alternatively run `omf reload`. What's the output of `omf list`?

Comment: yes. Do you happen to know where plugins are stored and where I can select them in which config file? In this respect I find zshell much easier to handle.

Comment: Should be under `~/.config/omf/`, I suppose in `bundle` – see https://github.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish#startup.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a permanent (neither a "clean" one, I think).

It is indeed possible to make the plugins work by putting the function.fish script into the ~/.config/fish/functions folder. This is a raw fix which I don't necessarily like but it works.